# Does couchbase actually support datasets larger than memory?

Tags: couchbase

Couchbase documentation says that "Disk persistence enables you to perform backup and restore operations, and enables you to grow your datasets larger than the built-in caching layer," but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am testing Couchbase 2.5.1 on a three node cluster, with a total of 56.4GB memory configured for the bucket.  After ~124,000,000 100-byte objects -- about 12GB of raw data -- [it stops accepting additional puts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0bxU.jpg).  1 replica is configured.

Is there a magic "go ahead and spill to disk" switch that I'm missing?  There are no suspicious entries in the errors log.

Answer (score 2):

It does support data greater than memory - see [Ejection and working set management](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#ejection-and-working-set-management) in the manual.

In your instance, what errors are you getting from your application? When you start to reach the low memory watermark, items need to be *ejected* from memory to make room for newer items.

Depending on the disk speed / rate of incoming items, this can result in `TEMP_OOM` errors being sent back to the client - telling it needs to temporary back off before performing the set, but these should generally be rare in most instances. Details on handling these can be found in the [Developer Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#handling-temporary-out-of-memory-errors).

Comment: Yes, it is recording TEMP_OOM situations, but as you can see from the linked graph, even after an hour it does not accept additional writes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that it's not the raw data that is filling up your memory, but the metadata associated with it. Couchbase 2.5 needs 56 bytes per key, so in your case that would be approximately 7GB of metadata, so much less than your memory quota.

But... metadata can be fragmented on memory. If you batch-inserted all the 124M objects in a very short time, I would assume that you got at least a 90% fragmentation. That means that with only 7GB of useful metadata, space required to hold it has filled up your RAM, with lots of unused parts in each allocated block.

The solution to your problem is to defragment the data. It can either be achieved manually or triggered as needed :

- manually : [image]
- automatically : [image]

If you need more insights about why compaction is needed, you can read [this blog article from Couchbase](http://blog.couchbase.com/compaction-magic-couchbase-server-20).

Comment: Interesting idea.  So if this works, I should expect it to hit theoretical maximum of about an 8x larger dataset with perfect defragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Even if none of your documents is stored in RAM, CouchBase still stores all the documents IDs and metadata in memory(this will change in version 3), and also needs some available memory to run efficiently. The relevant section in the docs:
http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#memory-quota

Note that when you use a replica you need twice as much RAM. The formula is roughly:

(56 + avg_size_of_your_doc_ID) * nb_docs * 2 (replica) * (1 + headroom) / (high_water_mark)

So depending on your configuration it's quite possible 124,000,000 documents require 56 Gb of memory.